# How to use socket.io in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to use socket.io in localhost which is my development environment:

client code:

```
const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:4000/');
socket.emit('trim-movie/go', data);
socket.on('trim-movie-response', trimResponse);
```

server :

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log('server is online...'));
const io = socket(server);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on('trim-movie/go', (data) => trimMovie(data, socket));
});
```

But I get this error:

> socket.io.js?v=1:1415          GET
> https://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OI2OmiX
> 404 (Not Found)

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that socket io uses `ws` protocol, not `https`

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: `io.connect('ws://localhost:4000/')`

Comment: it brings : `socket.io.js?v=1:1415          GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OI2QjQX net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: actually just use `io.connect(':4000')`

Comment: it again have shows this one: `socket.io.js?v=1:1415          GET https://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OI2RW0X 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I doubt it, try again

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone Love that confidence Sir, you're right, my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Your client shows an `https` URL.  Your server is starting an `http` server, NOT an `https` server because `app.listen()` only starts an `http` server.  There's no way and https url will connect to an http server so these will ever match up.

Change the client to:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/');
```

Or, if your page is already loaded from that same server, you can just use:

```
const socket = io();
```

and the client will get the domain and port from the URL of the containing web page.

Also make sure that the server-side `port` variable is set to 4000.